# attribute error in python (code-skulpor)

Tags: python

im trying to run the following code on codeskulptor. and its giving an error:
Line 17: AttributeError: 'card' object has no attribute 'rank'. y is this so?

```
import simplegui

ranks=('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K')
suits=('C','S','H','D')

card_centre=(36.5,49)
card_size=(73,98)
tiled_image=simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/cards.jfitz.png")

class card:
    def _init_(self,suit,rank):
        self.rank=rank
        self.suit=suit

    def draw(self,canvas,loc):
        global ranks,suits
        i=ranks.index(self.rank)
        j=suits.index(self.suit)
        card_pos=[card_centre[0]+i*card_size[0],card_centre[1]+j*card_size[1]]
        canvas.draw_image(tiled_image,card_pos,card_size,loc,card_size)

def draw(canvas):
    one_card.draw(canvas,[300,200])

frame=simplegui.create_frame("Card draw",600,400)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
one_card=card('H','J')
frame.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this really is the problem, but your `_init_` method should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, suit, rank):
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
```

Note that it has two `__` instead of just one `_`. This will make it a *constructor* (instead of just some method that happens to be called `_init_`), and only then it will actually be called when you create your `card` instance with `one_card = card('H','J')` and only then the attributes `self.rank` and `self.suit` will get initialized.

However, *if* this is the problem, you should actually get another error even before that, namely `TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments` because there is no constructor defined that takes two parameters, but maybe your IDE can statically (before actually running the program) recognize the one problem but not the other.

Comment: Yes, That was exactly the problem. Thank you :)